# Arithmetic and quadratic mean: Distance between $v$ and $(v+w)/2$ vs distance between $\sqrt{(v^2 + w^2)/2}$ and $(v+w)/2$

Tags: linear-algebra, means

Let $\textbf{v} = (v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n_{\geq 0}$ and $\textbf{w} = (w_1, w_2, \dots, w_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n_{\geq 0}$ be such that each $v_i \geq 0$ and each $w_i \geq 0$. 
Moreover, $\textbf{v} \neq \textbf{w}$.
Define the "arithmetic mean" of $\textbf{v}$ and $\textbf{w}$ by

$$\textbf{a} = \left( \frac{v_1 + w_1}{2}, \frac{v_2 + w_2}{2}, \dots, \frac{v_n + w_n}{2} \right) \in \mathbb{R}^n_{\geq 0}.$$

For lack of a better term, define the "quadratic mean" (or "root mean square") of $\textbf{v}$ and $\textbf{w}$ by

$$\textbf{q} = \left( \sqrt{\frac{v_1^2 + w_1^2}{2}}, \sqrt{\frac{v_2^2 + w_2^2}{2}}, \dots, \sqrt{\frac{v_n^2 + w_n^2}{2}} \right) \in \mathbb{R}^n_{\geq 0}.$$

I want to show that **q** is closer to **a** than **v** is. 
Specifically, with

$$d(\textbf{x},\textbf{y}) = \sqrt{\sum_{i = 1}^n (x_i - y_i)^2}$$

denoting the Euclidean distance between $\textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\textbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, I want to show that

$$d(\textbf{q},\textbf{a}) < d(\textbf{v},\textbf{a}).$$

I have tried millions of random $\textbf{v}$ and $\textbf{w}$ without finding a counter-example, so I am quite sure that this is true.
Any help on proving this is appreciated!

Comment: The diagram given in this Wikipedia article may help you (the proof seemed intuitive when I saw this diagram) https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @ShreyasS. I can see how it works for $n = 1$, but I fail to see how to generalize it. If you could briefly explain the intuition, then that would be very helpful!

Comment: @J G In your case you're just dealing with $n$ pairs of numbers. That diagram shows that it's true for any 2 numbers. After all, you just wanted to prove that the Q.M. of 2 numbers is closer to A.M than the numbers are, right?

Comment: @ShreyasS: Yes, I guess you are right. It is closer in each coordinate, $| v_i - a_i | = | w_i - a_i | \geq q_i - a_i$, so it's closer overall. Thanks!